# XPages data source hide until view entry clicked

Tags: xpages

Currently I have an XPage with a view data source and below it a document data source shown in edit mode. When clicking on the view entry that document gets loaded into the document data source in read mode. Cool.

But ...

How can I hide the document data source until a view entry is clicked?
How can I open the document data source in edit mode?
How can I hide the document data source once saved?

Comment: how do you initialize DDS? if you use documentID property, your DDS is empty and you can use DDS.isNewNote(). and I supose by "hiding DDS" you mean to hide fields binded to that DDS...

Comment: Have the Document data source in a custom control/panel and set that not to render until a view entry is clicked.